# Issues writing to a file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file-writing

I've been working on a game on my own and I'm having issues writing to a simple text file I'm using to hold data for the login panel. I'm using java.swing to create everything. Just wondering if anyone can see my issue.

```
public class Main {

private static String username;
private static String password;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try { FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("data.txt", true); //creates txt file for data
          PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw); //creates writer to move data to txt file
        }

    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } //catches error with writing to txt file



    getVariables(); //sets private variables to login info on text file
    login();    //opens login frame
}

public static void login(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");      //creates JFrame for login window

    frame.setResizable(false);                              
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //FRAME SETTINGS
    frame.setSize(180,140);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();    //creates panel for login window
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel usernameL = new JLabel("Username:"); //username label for login window
    usernameL.setSize(100,20);
    usernameL.setLocation(5,5);

    JLabel passwordL = new JLabel("Password:"); //password label for login window
    passwordL.setSize(100,20);
    passwordL.setLocation(5,25);


    final JTextField usernameField = new JTextField("",15); //username field for login window
    usernameField.setSize(100,20);
    usernameField.setLocation(70,5);

    final JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField("",15); //password field for login window
    passwordField.setSize(100,20);
    passwordField.setLocation(70,25);

    JButton confirmLogin = new JButton("Log In");       //button to login
    confirmLogin.setSize(80,20);
    confirmLogin.setLocation(45,50);
    confirmLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        //checks to see if login is correct
            if(usernameField.getText().equals(username) && passwordField.getText().equals(password)){
                gameMenu();         //calls game menu 
            }
            else {
                String message = "Your username or password is wrong!";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog                           //displays panel stating login was incorrect
                (new JFrame(), message, "Login Failed",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    JButton createAccount = new JButton("Create Account"); //button to create account
    createAccount.setSize(122,20);
    createAccount.setLocation(25,75);
    createAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        //calls method to create account
            createAccount();
        }
    });

    panel.add(createAccount);
    panel.add(passwordField);
    panel.add(usernameField);
    panel.add(usernameL);           //add components to window
    panel.add(passwordL);
    panel.add(confirmLogin);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

protected static void createAccount() {
    final JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Account Creation");       //creates window for account creation
    frame2.setSize(290,110);
    frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);       //window settings
    frame2.setResizable(false);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(null);                 //creates panel for account creation window

    JLabel usernameL2 = new JLabel("Username:");
    usernameL2.setSize(100,20);             //creates username label for window
    usernameL2.setLocation(55,5);

    JLabel passwordL2 = new JLabel("Password:");    //creates password label for window
    passwordL2.setSize(100,20);
    passwordL2.setLocation(55,25);

    final JTextField usernameField2 = new JTextField("",15);
    usernameField2.setSize(100,20);             //creates username field for window
    usernameField2.setLocation(120,5);

    final JPasswordField passwordField2 = new JPasswordField("",15);
    passwordField2.setSize(100,20);         //creates password field for window
    passwordField2.setLocation(120,25);

    JButton confirm = new JButton("Confirm Creation");
    confirm.setSize(130,20);            //creates button to confirm account creation
    confirm.setLocation(75,50);
    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try { FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("out.txt", false);         //doesnt append (should overwrite data)
              PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);                     

              pw.println(usernameField2.getText());         //gets info from textfield and pushes to data txt file
              pw.println(passwordField2.getText());         //gets info from textfield and pushes to data txt file
              pw.close();                               //closes printwriter and saves data file

              String message = "Account created succesfully!";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (new JFrame(), message, "",                 //displays panel stating account creation was succesful
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                frame2.dispose();

        } 
            catch (IOException g) { g.printStackTrace(); }

        }});

    panel2.add(confirm);
    panel2.add(usernameL2);
    panel2.add(passwordL2);         //add components to account creation window
    panel2.add(usernameField2);
    panel2.add(passwordField2);
    frame2.add(panel2);
    frame2.setVisible(true);

}

public static void gameMenu(){

    System.out.println("IT WORKS!");            //testing to make sure filewriting works
}

public static void getVariables(){

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("data.txt");         //gets ready to read from data file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            if((str = br.readLine()) != null && i == 0) {           //reads first line and saves it
                username = str;
            }
            if((str = br.readLine()) != null && i == 1) {           //reads second line and saves it
                password = str;
            }
        }

        br.close();                     //closes reader

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Instead of challenging people to hunt and guess what your problem might be, you should [edit] your question to add details about what happened when you compiled and ran this code, and how that's different from what you wanted. If an unexpected exception was thrown, then add the stack trace output, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(i == 0 && (str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            username = str;
        }
        if(i == 1 && (str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            password = str;
        }
    }
```

The code that you are using doesn't work because the first if statement will consume the second line even if `i` is not `0`.

A simpler way of reading the lines will be this:

```
for(int i = 0; (str = br.readLine())!=null && i < 2;i++){
     if(i == 0){
        username = str;
     }else{
        password = str;
     }
}
```

Also in the `getVariables()` method you should probably read the `out.txt` file instead of `data.txt`. From the code that you've posted it seems that no data is written to the `data.txt` file.